# Feeding 2D tensor into RRN/LSTM layer

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, time-series, tensorflow-datasets

I have the following dataset:

```
for x, y in ds_train.take(1):
    print(i, j)
```

Output:

```
tf.Tensor(
[[-0.5         0.8660254  -0.67931056 -0.7338509   0.          0.
   0.          0.          0.          0.          1.          0.
   0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
   0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.        ]
...
 [-0.5         0.8660254  -0.9754862  -0.22006041  0.          0.
   0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
   0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
   0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.        ]],
shape=(36, 24), dtype=float32) tf.Tensor([0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0], shape=(8,), dtype=int64)
```

I want to feed this data into RNN Layer:

```
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
  tf.keras.layers.SimpleRNN(40, input_shape=(36,24)),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(8),
])

model.compile(loss='mae', optimizer='adam')
history = model.fit(ds_train, epochs=100)
```

I get the following error:

```
ValueError: Input 0 of layer "sequential_12" is incompatible with the layer:
expected shape=(None, 36, 24), found shape=(None, 24)
```

I don't understand why `found shape` is equal to `(None, 24)`. We can see above, the shape of the tensor in the dataset is equal to `(36, 24)`. What is the proper way to feed such data (where 0-axis is a time, e.g. 36 timestamps and 24 features) into RNN/LSTM layer?

UPDATE: As @AloneTogether pointed, I need to batch my data first. In this case, I get another error:

```
    File "/home/mykolazotko/miniconda3/envs/tf/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keras/losses.py", line 1455, in mean_absolute_error
      return backend.mean(tf.abs(y_pred - y_true), axis=-1)
Node: 'mean_absolute_error/sub'
required broadcastable shapes
     [[{{node mean_absolute_error/sub}}]] [Op:__inference_train_function_32704]
```

It looks like the loss function doesn't like my target tensor with the shape `(8,)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try changing your `input_shape`, which currently only considers the features dimension:

```
tf.keras.layers.SimpleRNN(40, input_shape=(36, 24))
```

And don't forget to set a batch size on your dataset:

```
ds_train = ds_train.batch(your_batch_size)
```

Otherwise, 36 will be misunderstood as your batch dimension.

Here is a working example:

```
import tensorflow as tf

x = tf.random.normal((50, 36, 24))
y = tf.random.uniform((50, 8), dtype=tf.int32, maxval=2)

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
  tf.keras.layers.SimpleRNN(40, input_shape=(36,24)),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(8),
])

ds_train = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x, y)).batch(2)

model.compile(loss='mae', optimizer='adam')
history = model.fit(ds_train, epochs=100)
```

Make sure your labels really do always have 8 elements for each sample.

Comment: Yes, I need to batch it! Thank you!

Comment: I have updated my question. Do you have any Idea why I get the error with my loss function?

Comment: See updated answer @MykolaZotko